# Subversion Backup

Tags: .net, windows, svn

I've read a few posts about backing up Subversion (on Windows) in particular [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33055/what-is-the-best-way-to-backup-subversion-repositories).

It was my intention to simply do a backup of the folder where my repository is located each evening to a network share. I'm now guessing this is not sufficient? My checked out source code folder is 412MB yet my repository is only 287MB.

Any suggestions as to a windows backup strategy?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct your checkout will always be bigger than the repository itself.
backing up the repo folders is the way to go.

this is due to the way the repo store the files and their changes.