# creating a backup of svn folder with multi repository in another server and synchronizing them everyday

Tags: svn, database-backups, svnsync

I am trying to create have a backup server for my current svn repositories. I thought of using svnsync but it only sync one repo.

Another way I have thought about is to dump every repo and load them into the backup server but it seems too costly. Is there other ways to resolve this? At the same time I want to be able to copy over new commits to the backup server at the end of each day.

Comment: I'm sure there's loads of approaches and ideas out there when Googling `how to backup svn repo`. Not sure this needs a separate Stack Overflow question.

Comment: See e.g. https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-repository-backup.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500813/how-to-backup-svn-repository

Answer (score 0):

After trying out the number of ways to backup, here are what I think of the different solutions.

1. taking snapshots (if possible)

   - its fast and does not take up a lot of space
   - able to have multiple backup copies
2. svnsync

   - its simple to implement
   - can take quite long for the first sync
   - after first sync, it copies only changes
3. do svnadmin dump then load on backup server

   - each time you need to do a backup it takes too long
   - can be costly as you need to have extra space to store the dump before you transfer to the backup server
4. hotcopy

   - is relatively faster then dumping
   - but you need to pause the server as it can't be access while copying