# Taking backup of SVN repository with full history

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, backup

I need to take a backup of SVN repository on local machine with full history so that I can compare revisions and see comments after deleting the repository from server. I am using TortoiseSVN as client and unfuddle as repository server. Actually my account will be expired from unfuddle withing few days and I need to get the repo on my local system for further process.

How should I move?

Comment: You have no access to repo files themselves, right?

Comment: I have the access currently but in future I will not. And now I am to take the backup on local machine.

Comment: If you have access to the repo itself (not just read-write acces via svn interface), but data files - you can just copy them locally and you will get a local repo equal to the remote one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [svnsync](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.ref.svnsync.html) to download a full copy of the repository including history. It basically just copies every changeset to a local path of your choosing. I have used this for backup in the past, and it works like a charm.

There is a tutorial that explains how to do this on Windows: http://creekcodes.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-svnsync-on-windows.html

Comment: Do this need to first create a repo on my local machine? I mean svn server should be setup to my local machine first then create a repo and then sync it??

Comment: You must create a new repo on your local machine. I have updated my answer with a tutorial which explains how this is achieved on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

- **Real** backup - [svnadmin dump](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.dump.html) and [svnadmin load](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.load.html)
- Geekish backup - [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Mercurial) ([TortoiseHG](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/)) + [hgsubversion](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HgSubversion). Pull + push + offline mode

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`svnrdump`](http://rsvndump.sourceforge.net/) which is since version 1.7 available in the [original Subversion distribution](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnrdump.c.dump.html) and thus fully supported.

This tool is similar to `svnadmin dump` but dumps *remote* repositories. For how to use, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20362633/1548942) answer.

Answer (score -1):

WordAligned gives some tips and three ways of doing a mirror of a svn repository - ways one could also use for backup. Have a look at [this link](http://wordaligned.org/articles/how-to-mirror-a-subversion-repository).