# Backup Assembla hosted SVN repositories to windows

Tags: svn

Right now I have all of my files hosted using Assembla.com 's free hosting for svn repositories. I want to download all of my repositories to my local computer to store them as backups. Are there any applications built for windows that simply let me point to the svn repository and download the files to back them up? Or is there a better way of backing up my repository?

All of the other questions I've seen on SO are talking about if you have the server running on your own machine.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assembla allows you to export your repository through their web app. Go to your Source/SVN tab and then to the Export/Import subtab to download a dump of your repository

Comment: Once I have a dump of my repository what can I do with that?

Comment: Can this be automated?  I don't see how.

Answer (score 6):

Obviously, as you have already figured it out, in the case of hosted svn (assembla as an example) repository cannot be dumped using `svnadmin dump` utility becuase you do not have administrative access to the subversion server.

It can be mirrored instead. This could be done using `svnsync` utility.
Detailed steps of how to perform mirroring of remote repository are described in the [official svn documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.replication). As this replication manual describes, in order to successfully perform mirroring, you will need to initialize your local repository with `svnadmin crate` and start svn server using `svnserve -d -r [local_path_to_your repository]`. After you have your repository up and running, you will run `svnsync initialize` and `svnsync synchronize` in order to establish mirror of remote repository.

You could do `svnadmin dump` after you have successfully synchronized your local repository with the remote one. It is also described in [official svn documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate). As you already have noticed, there are many great answers about how to do this on stackoverlow. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33055/what-is-the-best-way-to-backup-subversion-repositories), for example. But performing dump would be rather optional action as long as you will have your repository mirror as a result of svnsync operation.

Good luck!