# Backup of SVN repository, located on Linux server, to Windows Client

Tags: windows, svn, backup

I try to create a backup of my SVN repository, located on Linux server, from Windows command-line Subversion Client:

C:\project>svnadmin hotcopy svn://"URL_of_my_SVN_repository"/ C:/BACKUP

and receive following error:
svnadmin: E205000: 'svn://"URL_of_my_SVN_repository"/' is a URL when it should be a local path

How I can solve it? I need to initiate a backup my SVN repository from Windows PC (due to our network policy I have access to the Linux server port 3690 (SVN) only).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnadmin.html), you can't run `svnadmin` from a remote machine:

> Since svnadmin works via direct repository access (and thus can only be used on the machine that holds the repository), it refers to the repository with a path, not a URL.

Comment: Thank you! What solution you can recommend me for the backup with URL access?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar enough with SVN administration to help you there, but let's see what the collective mind of StackOverflow has to offer...

Comment: One of the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33055/what-is-the-best-way-to-backup-subversion-repositories) suggests [svnsync](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnsync.html).

Comment: An other way is to use _svnrdump_ . This very much works as _svnadmin dump_ but does support operations over the net.

Answer (score 1):

The standard approach to backing up to a remote location is to combine multiple tools:

1. Run `svnadmin` on the machine which serves svn.
2. Use a tool like `rsync` to copy that repo dump from the svn server to the machine which will be backed up.

If your network policy allows you to run an svn server on a machine, but not to schedule `svnadmin` backup jobs on that machine, then I think you need to re-consider your network policy.