# How to backup & restore Tortoise SVN in windows server?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, upgrade, windows-server-2008-r2

I have SVN subversion installed on a windows server 2003 machine.

I will upgrade this server by installing windows server 2008. how to back up the svn data and restore it later?

I googled but I have not found the solution that meets my case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SVN repository backup strategies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33055/svn-repository-backup-strategies)

Comment: [I googled too](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=svn%20backup).